# Error on sending mail on php

Tags: php

This is my php code for sending email.But shows Error message"message not send successful.I think the code is working because it shows the error message that i have given.But i can't find out what error is in my code. please help me.Please suggest any way to clear this error.
And thank you in advance .

```
if (!empty($_POST['nume']) || !empty($_POST['email']) ) {
$email_to = "indeetvous@bbox.fr";
$email_subject = "Contact Form Indeetvous:";

$first_name = $_POST['nume']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['companie']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$comments = $_POST['mesaj']; // required

$email_message ="";
$email_message .= "First Name: ".($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".nl2br($comments)."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {

echo '                              <div id="contact_div">
Message Sent Successfully. Thank You for your interest in us.
</div>
<div id="contact_info">
<ul>

<li>
3, Allée de l\'Erdre
</li>

<li>44000 Nantes</li>

<li><a class="link"   

href="mailto:indeetvous@bbox.fr">indeetvous@bbox.fr</a></li>
<li>Téléphone : 02 40 48 73 91</li>
</ul>
<a href="#locatie" id="contact_link">SEE LOCATION</a>
</div>

';
 } else {

echo '                              <div id="contact_div">
Message Sending Failed. Try Again Later.
</div>
<div id="contact_info">
<ul>
<li>3, Allée de l\'Erdre </li>
<li>44000 Nantes</li>

<li><a class="link"   

href="mailto:indeetvous@bbox.fr">indeetvous@bbox.fr</a></li>
<li>Téléphone : 02 40 48 73 91</li>
</ul>
<a href="#locatie" id="contact_link">SEE LOCATION</a>
</div>

';
}

}


?>
```

Comment: Why do so many people use `Reply-to` when it's the same as `From`? The only reason to use `Reply-to` is when you want replies to go somewhere other than the `From` address.

Comment: Where does the message `message not send successful` come from? The message in your code is `Message Sending Failed`,

Comment: Actually error message is Message Sending Failed. Try Again Later.That was mistake made my me sorry.

Comment: Is it so hard to cut and paste the exact error message, instead of confusing us like this?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` so you see the error message coming from the `mail()` function.

Comment: Got these errors:PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<'  on line 21

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 19

Comment: There are no line numbers in your question, which lines are those?

Comment: You're probably missing a quote or semicolon somewhere before those lines.

Comment: Beware: Even if you do get this working, you are risking being hacked with this code because you're not sanitising your post variables to make them suitable for use with the `mail()` function. Specifically, `$mail_from` could have line feeds injected by an attacker to break your mail headers and send arbitrary content. If you want to avoid this kind of thing, I strongly recommend using a decent quality mail library like [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead of the raw `mail()` function.

Comment: Which lines are the errors happening on?

Answer (score 1):

Please replace following line:

```
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n"
```

with this line:

```
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n";
```

Comment: I made the same mistake. There's more to that line, but he has a bunch of spaces so you have to scroll to see it.

Comment: Still unable to send email? Are you checking it on localhost or live?

Comment: Your code is working fine at here:

http://zitecode.com/atif/testemail.php

I just create two fields for textring.